# How do I print the value of a variable to a file as part of a string?

Tags: python, string

If I have:

```
a=10
b = 20
```

how do I write `10` and `20` separated by a tab to the file?  Doing:

```
myfile.write('a\tb')
```

just prints the literal string to the file.  How to substitute the values of `a` and `b` into the string?

Answer (score 4):

Python does not recognize variable names inside a string literal.  Instead, it treats them as normal text.

In order to do what you want, you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
myfile.write('{}\t{}'.format(a, b))
```

This will take the values of `a` and `b`, convert them into strings, and then insert them into the string `'{}\t{}'`.  The curly braces `{}` denote where the values will be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

They need to be outside the ''

```
myfile.write(str(a)+'\t'+str(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pythonic way of doing it

```
with open('Filename.fileformat', 'w') as f:
    a="10"
    b="20"
    lst = [a,b]
    for i in lst:
        print ''.join(i)
        f.write(str(''.join(i)) +'\n')
```

Comment: I agree with the use of `with` here, but the `for` loop is unnecessary, unless the problem becomes more complex..

Comment: I just love adding loops to everything, the list is in case he wanted to add more variables.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use formatted string for that

```
myfile.write('%d\t%d' % (a, b))
```